# Unmarshal field of nested struct not work

Tags: json, go, types, marshalling, unmarshalling

Given the following structs

```
type Foo struct {
    Thing time.Duration `json:"thing"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
    Entry time.Duration `json:"entry"`
}
```

I want to custom `time.Duration` format and load `Bar` value from json string like:

```
{
  "thing": "hour",
  "entry": "second"
}
```

So I override `UnmarshalJSON` for `Foo` and `Bar` (https://play.golang.org/p/6v71eG_Xr98):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    Thing time.Duration `json:"thing"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Foo
    Entry time.Duration `json:"entry"`
}

func timeConvert(s string) time.Duration {
    if s == "hour" {
        return time.Hour
    }
    if s == "second" {
        return time.Second
    }
    return time.Duration(0)
}

func (t *Foo) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias Foo
    a := struct {
        Thing string `json:"thing"`
        *Alias
    }{Alias: (*Alias)(t)}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    t.Thing = timeConvert(a.Thing)
    fmt.Printf("Foo: %v [%v]\n", *t, err)
    return err
}

func (t *Bar) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias Bar
    a := struct {
        Entry string `json:"entry"`
        *Alias
    }{Alias: (*Alias)(t)}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    t.Entry = timeConvert(a.Entry)
    fmt.Printf("Bar: %v [%v]\n", *t, err)
    return err
}

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{"entry": "second", "thing": "hour"}`)
    json.Unmarshal(data, &Bar{})
}
```

But it outputs unexpected:

```
Foo: {1h0m0s} [<nil>]
Bar: {{1h0m0s} 0s} [<nil>]
```

**Why `Entry` value is incorrect?**

Comment: entry has the value 0s it which is the expected value i think

Comment: @loggerhead the problem is that you're embedding the alias, and while using the alias type will avoid calling UnmarshalJSON recursively on Bar, it will still call it on Foo, which is embedded in Bar and therefore also in Alias, so the logic in Foo's UnmarshalJSON is executed and because of that the "entry" is never unmarshaled because it's not present in Foo.

Comment: @loggerhead if you're able to change the types for Entry and Thing, I would recommend creating a custom duration type. (https://play.golang.org/p/0AoWtr30fdZ)

Comment: @mkopriva You are correct, thank you! But custom duration type is inconvenient to call functions in `time` package. I figure out one solution, and I'll answer myself. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for mkopriva. I found out because 'json.Unmarshal' works on any type, it gives me a hint that all type have implemented 'UnmarshalJSON' function, but it's NOT.

The calling of 'json.Unmarshal' on 'Bar' will actually do the following things:

1. calling `UnmarshalJSON` on `Bar`.
2. Because anonymous struct in `Bar` don't implemented `UnmarshalJSON`, so calling `UnmarshalJSON` on it's embedding struct `Foo` instead.

That's why 'Entry' in anonymous struct will not be unmarshal.

mkopriva suggest use a custom type to get the custom parsing, but it's inconvenient when you need pass it as argument on functions in the `time` package. I figure out another way to do it (just unmarshal twice, see https://play.golang.org/p/2ahDX-0hsRt):

```
func (t *Bar) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Alias Bar
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, (*Alias)(t)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var tmp struct {
        Entry string `json:"entry"`
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp)
    t.Entry = timeConvert(tmp.Entry)
    fmt.Printf("Bar: %v [%v]\n", *t, err)
    return err
}
```